# PySpark on Windows: Hive issues

Tags: python, apache-spark, hive, pyspark

I'm trying to run LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS from Mllib and I get many Hive issues:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o337.trainLogisticRegressionModelWithLBFGS.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient;
```

The fact is I didn't even install Hive... But why does this function rely on Hive? It is written nowhere in the documentation... Is it a prerequisite to install Hive to run any Mllib function?

Comment: can you show the code you trying to run?

Comment: It's a bit long, that's why I didn't give all details. I use SparkContext.textFile to read the input files. The documentation says it supports local file systems.

Answer (score 1):

A Hive installation is not needed, but Spark needs Hive-compatible classes to operate on DataFrame objects, such as those within an ML pipeline step.

The `pip install pyspark`, for example, doesn't come with these (or any Hadoop) libraries, as far as I know.

If you downloaded Spark with Hadoop from the Apache site, then you will get Hive libraries and a `bin/pyspark` script. On windows, though, you might need to setup WinUtils.